# Python-AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'decode'" when trying to call the GML file on NetworkX

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, networkx, gml-geographic-markup-lan

### Premise・What I want to achieve

I'm going to use Python to read the GML file.

### Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "firstgml.py", line 9, in <module>
    G = nx.read_gml(gml_path)
  File "<decorator-gen-434>", line 2, in read_gml
  File "/Users/XXXX/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/networkx/utils/decorators.py", line 227, in _open_file
    result = func_to_be_decorated(*new_args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/XXXX/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/gml.py", line 218, in read_gml
    G = parse_gml_lines(filter_lines(path), label, destringizer)
  File "/Users/XXXX/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/gml.py", line 398, in parse_gml_lines
    graph = parse_graph()
  File "/Users/XXXX/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/gml.py", line 387, in parse_graph
    curr_token, dct = parse_kv(next(tokens))
  File "/Users/XXXX/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/gml.py", line 315, in tokenize
    for line in lines:
  File "/Users/XXXX/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/gml.py", line 209, in filter_lines
    line = line.decode('ascii')
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

## Corresponding source code

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

gml_path = "XXXX.gml"
gml_path = gml_path.encode("utf-8")
G = nx.read_gml(gml_path)
X = np.array(nx.to_numpy_matrix(G))
print(nx.is_directed(G))
```

### What I tried

I changed the encoding character code to ascii and so on, but I get an error.

### Supplementary information (FW / tool version, etc.)

Python 3.85

networkx 2.1

numpy 1.19.2

Comment: Looks like your gml file contain a line which in an 'int' so `line = line.decode('ascii')` raise the exception. You can share the gml file.

Comment: Why do you encode the path before sending it to `read_gml`?

Comment: @balderman I've added the gml file to the question

Comment: @Marko if I don't encode,error occurs "NetworkXError: input is not ASCII-encoded"

Comment: What is the encoding of your GML file?

Comment: @Marko The encoding of the gml file is utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the part that is wrong.

```
gml_path = "XXXX.gml"
gml_path = gml_path.encode("utf-8")
G = nx.read_gml(gml_path)
```

You shouldn't be encoding the name of the file. `read_gml` takes a filename or a filehandle. When you pass the encoded `gml_path` it thinks it is an open file, so it goes to iterate over it. And when it goes to do `line.decode('ascii')`, the `line` variable contains `b'X'` which transfers to the number 88.

```
gml_path = "XXXX.gml"
gml_path = gml_path.encode("utf-8")
print(gml_path[0])
>>> 88
```

The error you were getting before: `"NetworkXError: input is not ASCII-encoded"` is because your file is not properly encoded, not your path to file. What you should do is remove this line `gml_path = gml_path.encode("utf-8")`, and encode your GML file, either with another tool, or using Python.